# Flash & Backbone.js - How to make routing links work without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, backbone.js, actionscript-2

Supposedly I have a page (**"A.php"**) using Backbone.js with the following route defined:

```
routes: {
    'item/:num': 'showItem'
}
```

And there is a Flash SWF that'll get embedded in both **A.php** and **B.php** (another page, without any Backbone structure).

Is there anyway to make it so that when a button inside this SWF is clicked, it will invoke the method bound with the route `'item/:num': 'showItem'` without a page reload if the SWF is on **A.php**, but performs normal linking behavior if it's on **B.php**?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up JavaScript functions with the same name in both A.php and B.php - for example, both pages have Javascript to define a `goToShowItem()` function.

A's function will call the Backbone routing code, B's function will simply set the `window.location` to the normal link address.

The button in your flash project will call `getURL("javascript:goToShowItem();");` to call the current page's `goToShowItem()` function.

Comment: Is there anyway to only plant the JS callback inside A.php, without planting anything on B.php?